# Why is my app made by App Inventor 2 not sending text messages?

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-6.0-marshmallow, app-inventor

When I tested my app, apparently no text message is being sent. The blocks are below:
[image: My Blocks.]

The funny thing is that this simple app I made in 30 seconds worked perfectly:[image: The simple app I made.]

Notice how the first four blocks of the *when Texting1.MessageRecived..do...* blocks are almost the same as each other.

Comment: My testing device is the Alcatel Aquire+ on AT&T, if that is any help. It is on Android 6.0 Marshmallow.

Comment: Did you try to simplify your program and narrow down problem area before?

Comment: I have. I have simplified it to the _when Texting1.MessageReceived..do.._ block.